# curious to know whether I can use Python to add users in Imperva Firewall

Tags: python, web-application-firewall, imperva

Greetings of the day!

I would like to know whether I will be able to add a user to Imperva WAF firewall using Python scripts ?
We add application, web sites, users to Imperva Firewall using Terraform and CI/CD.

Can we do the same using Python instead of using Terraform files ?

If so could you tell me how can I achieve this ?

Comment: This is Imperva Incapsula am curious about.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately managing users is not a function which the Imperva API provides.

Account users and their attributes may only be managed from the portal - https://docs.imperva.com/bundle/cloud-application-security/page/settings/account-users.htm